# Can't convert ArrayList<subtype> to ArrayList<type>

Tags: java, arraylist, type-conversion

I'm writing a program to simulate an artificial neural network. I have the following classes and interfaces set up:

```
public interface Neuron
{
}

// Input neuron
public class INeuron implements Neuron
{
}

// Output and hidden neuron
public class ONeuron implements Neuron
{
}

public interface Layer
{
    public ArrayList<Neuron> getNeurons();
}

// Input layer
public class ILayer implements Layer
{
    ArrayList<INeuron> neurons = new ArrayList<INeuron>();

    public ArrayList<Neuron> getNeurons()
    {
        return neurons;
    }

    // other stuff appropriate to the input layer
}
```

The compiler reports "cannot convert from ArrayList<INeuron> to ArrayList<Neuron>."

I've tried switching things around. For example: `ArrayList<Neuron> neurons = new ArrayList<INeuron>()`. But that just seems to shift the same error to different parts of the class.

I don't understand why INeuron can't be implicitly cast to Neuron since INeuron is a subtype of Neuron.

Comment: The right solution will depend on what your intended use for that returned list is (just reading? modifying?). A `Generic<SubType>` is not a `Generic<Type>` for good reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use:

```
public interface Layer
{
    public ArrayList<? extends Neuron> getNeurons();
}
```

because of lack of covariance and contravariance in generics. If you return an ArrayList < INeuron > as an ArrayList < Neuron > then you would potentially be able to add an element that is not a INeuron (like another child of Neuron) to an ArrayList < INeuron >

Answer (score 4):

Simply change:

```
ArrayList<INeuron> neurons = new ArrayList<INeuron>();
```

to:

```
ArrayList<Neuron> neurons = new ArrayList<Neuron>();
```

to be able to serve both types.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a bad thing that could happen.

```
void mymethod ( ILayer l )
{
     List<Neuron> neurons = l . getNeurons ( ) ;
     neurons . add ( new ONeuron ( ) ) ; // bad thing
}
```

My method `mymethod` just contaminated that `ILayer`'s `neurons` list with a non `INeuron`.

I recommend [Luciano's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10133422/348975).

Comment: Good catch! This is for a class (I'm the teacher). We'll change the API to use an Iterator next week.

Comment: @BarryBrown You'll have to deal with the same sort of issue for the Iterator as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that... Is there a better solution?

Comment: As trutheality said "The right solution will depend on what your intended use for that returned list".  Based on your code sample, I recommend Luciano's solution.  Why is that unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Layer <?> getNeurons();
```

This is another way to write subtype,right?